# Why am I not redirected to login page from projects page if user is disconnected?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

As describe is the jira SONAR-8000 , when I request the URL http://ly-sonar:9010/projects?gate=ERROR without previous authentification, I am not automatically redirected to the login page.
In the console, I have the following errors :
[WS api/users/current error 401](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiUhy.png)

I need to refresh the page to have a currentUser defined and be redirect to the login page.
My configuration required the user to be authenticated *sonar.forceAuthentication=true*

Do I have to set a specific parameters to avoid this ?

My Sonar server is in version 6.5

Comment: Are you using an external auth provider (e.g. GitHub)?

Comment: Hi welcome to Stackoverflow. You should consider reading the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to create a complete and answerable question.

Comment: @G. Ann : I am connected to an Active Directory.

Comment: Which version of the LDAP plugin are you using ?

Comment: I am using the LDAP plugin version 2.2.
After updating from Sonar 6.5 to Sonar 6.6, the redirection is now fixed and works correctly.